# Why are we using "interested" instead "interesting" in the next phrase

Tags: word-meaning

I am learning English and I am having a question.

Look at the phrase:

> I have been interested in painting since I was ten.

I do not understand why we had used *interested* instead *interesting*. The phrase is *in the Present Perfect Continuous* or is not it?

Answer (score 2):

A person can be interested in something or someone. Someone or something can be interesting to someone.

Verb participles can be used as adjectives.

Interested can be an adjective meaning 'having a feeling of interest'.

> interested
>   adjective (FEELING INVOLVED)
>   wanting to give your attention to something and discover more about it:
>
> He didn't seem very interested in what I was saying.
>   She's at that age where she's starting to get interested in boys.
>   I'd be interested to hear more about your work.
>   "Really?" he said, with an interested look on his face.
>   Yes, I'd be very interested in knowing more about the services
>   your firm offers.

[Interested (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interested)

Interesting can be an adjective meaning 'able to keep the attention':

> interesting
>   adjective
>
> Someone or something that is interesting keeps your attention because
>   he, she, or it is unusual, exciting, or has a lot of ideas:
>
> She's quite an interesting woman.
>   She's got some very interesting things to say on the subject.
>   It is always interesting to hear other people's point of view.
>   Oh, I didn't know they were married - that's interesting.

[Interesting (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interesting)

Comment: Thank you so much. And what about time? It is in the Present Perfect Continuous?

Comment: What is your question? Have you read anything about the present perfect continuous?

Comment: What time is used in the sentence? It is all what I want to understand.

Comment: "I **have been** interested in painting since I was ten" - present perfect.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I thought otherwise. Some things become to clearer to me.